# Xcode 12 beta 1: po does not work in debugger

Tags: xcode, beta

When reaching a breakpoint during debugging, the console says:

```
2020-07-05 10:20:41.726165+0200 XXX[77358:16150444] [debug] insertSection
Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)(lldb)
```

After that, the „po“ command does not work:

```
(lldb) po structureItem 
(lldb)
```

While the „v“ command shows results:

```
(lldb) v structureItem
(XYZ.StructureItem) structureItem = 0x000060000168d580 {
…
}
(lldb)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is obviously fixed with Xcode beta 3. `po` is working again there as expected.

Comment: it isn't. I'm still getting it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63228186/xcode-12-beta-3-po-does-not-work-in-debugger

Comment: Since beta 3, I had no problems anymore.

Answer (score 0):

After beta 1 problem solved. but I used **fr v structureItem** instead of **po structureItem**

It's work for me. hope it's helpful to you.

Thank you.