# Xcode 12 beta 3: po does not work in debugger

Tags: ios, xcode

I'm not able to print any value in lldb and getting the message:

"Cannot create Swift scratch context (couldn't load the Swift stdlib)"

[image]

Does anyone know how to get around this problem?